# Finding time intersections with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Considering the following data structure:

```
{
    name: 'track1',
    durationSec: 300,
    tags: [
        {
            name: "mike", startSec: 15, endSec: 88
        },
        {
            name: "kate", startSec: 54, endSec: 140
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'track2',
    durationSec: 240,
    tags: [
        {
            name: "mike", startSec: 0, endSec: 150
        },
        {
            name: "kate", startSec: 200, endSec: 220
        }
    ]
```

Is it possible to find only tracks where for example the tags "mike" and "kate" have intersections (like above only track1 with intersection from second 54 to 88) with elasticsearch?

Comment: Do you know the name of the tags beforehand that you want to find intersections between?

Comment: Yes, the user should be able to search like "+mike +kate" and should only get tracks where these tags have intersections. So all tags are known beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to do with a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter/).

You might need to access the _source and not the doc since array values are flattened. See more about scripting [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting/).

Performance won't be a hoot though, since it requires both running a script and accessing the source. If you're not doing it over huge data it might be reasonable.